# How can i make an ppolicy for another attribute in openldap?

Tags: openldap

I've created a new attribute named "claveTelefonica" this a sort of password and i need to apply some policies to it, the thing is i'm already using pwdPolicy objectclass for the userPassword. In this case, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. OpenLDAP only supports password-policy via the `userPassword` attribute. It appears to make this configurable, but only this one value is actually supported.